# Take photo from front camera using intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I'm using intent to call the camera to capture a photo, but this time I need to call the front camera instead of the rear one. So is this possible in android, and if so how can I make the call?

Here is what I'm doing right now:

```
intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            photoImageFile = ImageUtil.getTempFile(this);
            photoImagePath = photoImageFile.getPath();
            if(getIntent().getBooleanExtra(IntentConstants.FRONT_CAMERA,false)){
                //TODO call front camera
            }
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoImageFile));
            startActivityForResult(intent, RequestCode.FROMCAMERA);
```

Comment: @appoll that question doesnt solve my issue.. so that's why i posted this, maybe someone knows a new solution(if there is one existing)

Comment: There is nothing in the documentation for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` that offers something for this. Hence, few, if any, camera apps will offer this, and there are a *lot* of camera apps that users could use for fulfilling `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` requests.